# QGIS Rule-Based Labeling - Toggle child rules visibilty

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, style, filter

So it works to add labels by dragging it to another label, like it does in styles. But if I try to hide this upper filter, the contained labels won't hide.

Is this a bug, or is it not wanted, to set upper filters? Is there a workaround?

I've got to set 10 filters for 4 different labels, so I will get 40 filters after that. I've got no problem with that, but there will be many people, that will have to work with that styles/labels, and I don't want to confuse them.

My QGIS Version ist 2.18.

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "upper filter"? Also some more information on your intended style of labels would be helpful.

Comment: Welcom to GIS.SE! I think a better term would be parent (upper) or child (lower) rule. I agree that this might be confusing to unexperienced users, and I don't understand too, that with the feature to order rules in a tree structure (like in the legend) there is no way to toggle child rules label visibility by toggeling the parent rules visibilty. I think this would be worth rainsing an issue (https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/). Note that the described behaviour is the same for QGIS 3 and that you cannot raise issues for QGIS 2.x anymore.

Comment: I have the same question as @Erik because if it's about showing/hiding labels only and not about styling the labels, I'm sure the number of rules could be reduced.

Comment: Thanks for the replys guys. So @Jochen Schwarze basically understood what I meant, sorry for the poor description. Sad to here, that there is no workaround, and that it actually does not work.  I will raise an Issue on that...